# Vue2 Laravel5.3 Moving From Bootstrap4 to Bulma0.3

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bulma

I have been using bootstrap 4 for my laravel project but there seems to be some JS issue and I would like to try pure css package such as Bulma but I have no idea how to move from bootstrap 4 to Bulma.

I have installed Bulma by

```
npm install bulma
```

and uninstall Bootstrap by

```
npm uninstall bootstrap
```

then delete a line of code in my app.js as followings

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

and at localhost:8000/ console log has error as below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
>       at eval (eval at  (app.js:371), :7:27)
>       at Object. (app.js:371)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at app.js:64
>       at app.js:67

EDIT#1
so bootstrap.js is not the bootstrap4 it is referring to. and within bootstrap.js I have the following codes

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});
```

So as I uninstall bootstrap and now console log returns

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "bootstrap"

I would think that is because require('bootstrap') in this bootstrap.js so I remove it and try to do `require('bulma')` or `import bulma from 'bulma';` but either works. Did I misunderstand the way to use bulma in vue?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look inside your resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js you'll see that it requires Vue and lodash and jQuery and all your project dependancies, This is not an import for twitter bootstrap but for "bootstrapping" your application.

Here is some of the code in there:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Vue from 'vue';

window._ = _;
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
window.Vue = Vue;
```

This code assignes the $ for jQuery and Vue to the global window instance and this is the reason you get `Uncaught ReferenceError:Vue is not defined` once you remove this file.

You can simply import bulma inside this file or just use a `<link />` tag in your master page (It's just css, no need for npm in here, but you can if you really want it)

Comment: that makes perfect sense so far, thank you for your response @AfikDeri . I update my code in this bootstrap.js in my question. so there are still some questions about this can you please have a look at the question again? Thanks.

Comment: or I should import bulma in app.scss as it is css but no js required so it does not matter to Vue?